Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' building Consumer(dirty, dependencies: [UncontrolledProviderScope], state: _ConsumerState
I have a Riverpod provider which is this one:-

final StateProvider<List<Widget>> categoriesProvider = StateProvider((ref) {
  final Box categories = Hive.box("categoryDetails");
  final List<Widget> oldCategories =
      categories.get("categories", defaultValue: <Widget>[]);
  if (oldCategories.isNotEmpty) return oldCategories;
  return <Widget>[];
});


I made sure every part returns a List<Widget> so the error goes away but to no avail.
I have even tried to return only a <Widget>[] from the provider but the error doesn't go away.
This is my build method:-

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? _) {
        final List<Widget> children =
            ref.watch(categoriesProvider).cast<Widget>();
        return SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.27,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final List<Widget> updatedCategories =
                  List<Widget>.from(children);
              if (index == 0) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    updatedCategories.add(addContainer(context));
                    ref.read(categoriesProvider.notifier).state =
                        updatedCategories;
                  },
                  child: const AddCategoryContainer(),
                );
              } else {
                return GestureDetector(
                    onDoubleTap: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text("Confirm Deletion"),
                            content: const Text(
                                "Are you sure you want to delete this item?"),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                      .pop(); // Close the dialog
                                },
                                child: const Text("Cancel"),
                              ),
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  updatedCategories.removeAt(index - 1);
                                  ref.read(categoriesProvider.notifier).state =
                                      updatedCategories;
                                  Navigator.of(context)
                                      .pop(); // Close the dialog
                                },
                                child: const Text("Delete"),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: children[index - 1]);
              }
            },
            itemCount: children.length + 1,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            reverse: true,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }


To be precise, the error I'm getting is this:


The relevant error-causing widget was:
    Consumer Consumer:file:///F:/programming/Code/android/flutter/smartmenu/lib/containers/add_category_button.dart:89:12


You can see I'm type casting everything to get rid of the error but I don't know what's wrong.
I have tried to Flutter clean the project but it doesn't help
(I'm working on Windows)

Does this answer your question? Type inferring doesn't work properly when saving List of objects in Hive box

Try to narrowing cast the following returned value as List<Widget>
categories.get("categories", defaultValue: <Widget>[]) as List<Widget>;


Didn't work! It's a very weird  type of bug! It's like the whole riverpod package just stopped working

add_category_button.dart where's that dart file is it the provided in question, if not edit your question. the source of the error is in that file specifically line number 89 .
